# NeoVim - Single Redo my mapping containing an <Escape>

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, repeated-commands

Well I know it doesn't work because of the `<Esc>`, but is there any way to do it so that `.`(vim single redo) repeats the whole *mapping* and not only the part after the first `<Esc>` (**without** macros)?

I also tried replacing the `<Esc>` with `^o` (CTRL_o) but it didn't work either. Any ideas?

---

I have this inside my `init.vim`:

```
nnoremap <leader>list 0i- `<Esc>$a`<Esc>
```

Explanation:

- Jumps to start of the line
- Insert `` - ` ``
- Jump to end of the line
- Insert another `` ` ``

---

---

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not so simple, because pressing  `<Esc>` typically ends an undo change.

There is [:h i_CTRL-G_U](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-G_U), but this only works with the cursor keys, it doesn't help with using e.g. the `<end>` key.

However, if you change your mapping to perform the following:

Jump to the start of the line, change the rest of the line, insert your list characters `` - ` ``, get the rest of the line and add the back-quote character again `` ` ``, it should be repeatable. Something like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>list 0C-`<C-R>-`
```

This should be completely repeatable, with the exception of the *move cursor to the beginning of the line*, because cursor movements are not repeatable using `.` command.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for the smart idea, but this isn't working at all^^ **1.** as you said the `0` movement won't be used again, which is really important and **2.** The *Small Delete Register* (`-`) will be used over and over again, so you wll end up with the same line everywhere. Still interesting approach :)

Comment: 1) as said, `0` **is not repeatable** as `.` command and there is no way to make it configurable. 2). small delete register is repeatable starting from a later vim 9.x patch, so you may need to upgrade here (needs patch 8.2.2189)

Comment: **1.** As I said, you said it already xD I was just repeating it^^ **2.** Currently using `neovim 0.6.1`, the latest version... So I guess it is not possible with neovim^^

Comment: neovim 0.6.1 is quite old, are you sure there is no newer version?

Comment: oh wow yeah whoopsie sorry you are right. I was installing it with `apt`... `neovim 0.6.1` is older than a year. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: instead of `0C`, could you use `cc`?

Comment: Hm, I think then the small delete register may not be filled :/